# String processing in Asterisk

Tags: asterisk

In an Asterisk dialplan, is there any way to search for a character (or substring) in another string? I basically want to parse out the middle portion of a string, but the exact character positions will vary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is CUT function in asterisk dialplan.

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+func+cut

You also have

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+func+fieldqty

And replace

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+func+REPLACE

Those functions is enought for almost any task you may need.

Comment: How does this answer the question? Specifically, which of these 3 functions determines _whether_ the sub-string is present in the string, or _where_ it is present?

Comment: He is not asked WHERE. Asterisk have no strpos function analog, it really rare used. You can use CUT and LEN combination. Answer is perfectly describe what needed for task, parsing string by delimited(often need in asterisk). Note, that the question starter accepted this.

Comment: I realize that this might answer the question, I just feel it could be clearer to help us understand _how_ to do it. I don't understand how to use CUT and LEN combination to determine whether the substring is present in the string. Thanks for any clarification that you might provide.

Comment: CUT by char you are searching for, after that get first portion and check it's LEN. There is REGEXP command available too. Sorry, no STRPOS.

Comment: https://www.voip-info.org/asterisk-func-regex/

Comment: Thanks. I was able to get it working with STRREPLACE (replacing the searched for string with an empty string) followed by a LEN comparison (if there was a replace, the string is now shorter than the original), so I know there was a match. Has some quirky edge cases, but works for the most part.